# Elasticsearch - get N top items in group

Tags: elasticsearch

I keep such data in elasticsearch with such a structure.

```
 "_source" : {
              "artist" : "Roger McGuinn",
              "track_id" : "TRBIACM128F930021A",
              "title" : "The Bells Of Rhymney",
              "score" : 0,
              "user_id" : "61583201a0b70d3f7ed79b60",
              "timestamp" : 1634991817
            }
```

How can I get the top N songs with the best score for each user. If a user has rated a song several times, I would like to take into account only the most recent rating.

I'm done with this ,but instead the top 10 songs for the user, I just get the first 10 songs found, without including the score

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "group_by_user": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user_id.keyword",
        "size": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_track": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "track_id.keyword"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "take_the latest_score": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "timestamp",
                "size": 1
              },
              "aggs": {
                "take N tracks": {
                  "top_hits": {
                    "size": 10
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What I understand is that you'd want to return list of valid users with the highest rated track based on date/times.

You can make use of [Date Histogram](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-datehistogram-aggregation.html) aggregation followed by [Terms aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) on which you can further extend pipeline to include [Top Hits aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-top-hits-aggregation.html):

**Aggregation Query:**

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "size": 0, 
  "aggs": {
    "songs_over_time": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
        "fixed_interval": "1h",             <---- Note this. Change this to 1d if you'd want to return results on daily basis 
        "min_doc_count": 1
      },
      "aggs": {
        "group_by_user": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "user_id.keyword",
            "size": 10                      <---- Note this. To return 10 users
          },
          "aggs": {
            "take N tracks": {
              "top_hits": {
                "sort": [
                {
                  "score": {
                    "order": "desc".       <---- Also note this to sort based on score
                  }
                }],
                "_source": {
                  "includes": ["track_id", "score"].  <---- To return track_id and score
                }, 
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What this would give you for e.g since I'm using `fixed_interval` as `1h` is, for every hour, return all highest rated track of valid users in that time.

Feel free to filter out the docs using [Range Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html#ranges-on-dates) on which you can run the above aggregation query.